# SQL Reporting Services - Disaplying Left to right, up and down

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

Is there a way in SQL Reporting 2005 to display data in a column that prints left to right then up and down? Example:

```
Column 1        Column 2

  Adam            Bob
  Carl            Dick
  Eric            Fred
```

Instead of the current way which is:

```
 Column 1        Column 2

  Adam            Dick
  Bob             Erick
  Carl            Fred
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Horizontal tables](http://blogs.msdn.com/ChrisHays/archive/2004/07/23/193292.aspx) ...?

Answer (score 0):

3 ways I can think of.

Nothing pretty or natural though. The problems are that there is no standard control in SSRS, and there is no control data to use to manage layout in a standard control

First, Generate a dummy column, say using ROW_NUMBER() and modulo 2.
Use this to filter the dataset results into 2: bind each filtered set to side by side tables.

Second, use a matrix control in a rectangle
This will split pairs of rows about to side by side, use the rectangle grouping to split into pairs. You'll need a dummy column again to group on but going up 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 (hmmmm how to do that...)

Third, generate the dataset as 2 columns.
Self-join or PIVOT using a ROW_NUMBER() and modulo 2 column

Personally I'd tend to the 3rd option or 1st option.